# actix pass appliction state with string

Tags: rust, actix-web

Hello I want to pass the following AppState.

```
pub struct AppState {
    clients: Vec<Client>,
}
```

This is how I the server:

```
async fn launch_server(app_config: CmkClientServerConfig) -> std::io::Result<()> {
HttpServer::new(|| App::new()
    .data(Config::default().realm("Restricted area"))
    .data(AppState {
        clients: app_config.clients
    })
    .app_data(web::PayloadConfig::new(1000000))
    .service(web::resource("/").route(web::post().to(index))))
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .workers(1)
    .run()
    .await
}
```

The Client entity struct I want to pass:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Client {
    pub id: String,
    pub password: String,
}
```

I hope it is clear what I am trying to accomplish.
Now to my Problem.
Compiler says:

> the trait bound `entities::CmkClientServerConfig: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied in `[closure@src/server.rs:25:21: 31:66 app_config:entities::CmkClientServerConfig]

Maybe this thing needs to be cloned because of async execution.
So added "#[derive(Clone)]" to CmkClientServerConfig struct and the Client struct.

Then a get this error message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `app_config.clients`, as `app_config` is a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/server.rs:29:22
   |
23 | async fn launch_server(app_config: CmkClientServerConfig) -> std::io::Result<()> {
   |                        ---------- captured outer variable
...
29 |             clients: app_config.clients
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `app_config.clients` has type `std::vec::Vec<entities::Client>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `app_config.clients`, as `app_config` is a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/server.rs:29:22
   |
23 | async fn launch_server(app_config: CmkClientServerConfig) -> std::io::Result<()> {
   |                        ---------- captured outer variable
...
29 |             clients: app_config.clients
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `app_config.clients` has type `std::vec::Vec<entities::Client>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

My question is how to do it correctly, how can I make a clone possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cloning is necessary because it might have to be passed to multiple threads. The easiest way to do this is just to use an `Arc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [API docs](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/struct.App.html#method.data) and the [Get Started docs](https://actix.rs/docs/application/) explain:

> `HttpServer` accepts an application factory rather than an application instance. An `HttpServer` constructs an application instance **for each thread**. Therefore, **application data must be constructed multiple times**. If you want to share data between different threads, a shareable object should be used, e.g. `Send + Sync`.

If your `clients` list is only initialized on server start and otherwise stays immutable then you can just clone it in your app factory function, but if it's suppose to be mutable then you must wrap it in a `Arc<Mutex<T>>` so that it can safely be cloned, shared, and mutated across **the multiple threads running your app**.

If the `clients` list does not change then update your client to `derive` the `Clone` trait:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)] // Clone added here
pub struct Client {
    pub id: String,
    pub password: String,
}
```

And then update your app factory function to `move` your `app_config` into itself so you can repeatedly call `clone` on `clients`:

```rust
async fn launch_server(app_config: CmkClientServerConfig) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || App::new() // move added here
        .data(Config::default().realm("Restricted area"))
        .data(AppState {
            clients: app_config.clients.clone() // clone() added here
        })
        .app_data(web::PayloadConfig::new(1000000))
        .service(web::resource("/").route(web::post().to(index))))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .workers(1)
        .run()
        .await
}
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer. The clients list does not change. But how to make is cloneable. Adding '#[derive(Clone)]' does not work. I guess the Strings are the problem, but there must be I way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to address the problem of `app_config.clients` being moved. Just so you are on the same page, the clojure passed to `HttpServer::new` will be executed once per thread. So it would result in multiple moves out of `app_config.clients`. (Think about it and you will understand how actix works).

That said, this problem can be handled in one of the following ways depending upon which are possible:

1. Create new `Vec<Client>` for each thread like this:

```rust
...
.data(AppState {
        clients: create_new_clients()
    })
```

2. If your `Client` struct is `Clone` you can also do:

```rust
...
.data(AppState {
        clients: app_config.clients.clone()
    })
```

3. All else failing, you can wrap your clients within `Arc` like so:

```rust
pub struct AppState {
    clients: Vec<Arc<Client>>,
}
```

```rust
...
.data(AppState {
        clients: app_config.clients.clone()
    })
```

`Client` probably need mutability, please check the other answer suggesting `Arc<Mutex<Client>>` for that